# Editing a single field on a rendered node

Tags: organic-groups, comments

On a given content type called Tracking (which is also a Group), I have a title, OG fields, and a repeating text field called Log. I'd like a member of the OG to be able to enter a value and submit without entering the edit field.

The use case is a mobile site with observers in the field. They won't be editing the entire node. They're just taking notes into a repeating text field?

Is this possible or should I seek a different solution? Or should I just rely on Comments for such a function?

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever works for you. I've used the below modules to achieve this type of functionality before.

Look at [Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions):

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

And look at [Editable Fields](https://drupal.org/project/editablefields) to easily edit a field when not on the edit page:

> This module allows CCK fields to be edited on a node's display (e.g.
>   at node/123), not just on the node edit pages (e.g. node/123/edit). It
>   also works within views etc. Anywhere a 'formatter' can be selected,
>   you can select editable (or click to edit).

Or maybe [Editable Views](https://drupal.org/project/editableviews), modules:

> Editable Views lets you create Views where the fields can be edited.
>   Fields show both the current value and a form to edit it. A 'Save'
>   button allows saving of all the entities shown in the View.
>
> Editable fields can be added on the base entity as well as on entities
>   brought into the View by a relationship. Other, non-editable fields
>   may be added to the View, in which case they function normally.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [Edit module](https://drupal.org/project/edit) which is part of the [Spark distribution](https://drupal.org/project/spark).